# How to reply to Buddypress notifications?

Tags: buddypress

Currently, when I receive notifications from Buddypress, I have to log in the site to post a comment on an event, or a reply to a message.

Is there a way to reply directly in the MUA ? My idea was to generate a UUID that would be used as a reply-to field ,e.g. msg.59326d09-821e-4d32-b77c-096ac7507a02@reply.domain.com , find the related event when the message is received using postfix content filter, parse the email body to extract the reply, and to insert the comment into the database.

Is this secure? Can it be done without having high privileges on the server ?

Comment: Do you know what MTA software is running on your server?  This would make a difference to the answer.  For example, is it Postfix?

Comment: What exactly is a `MUA`?

Comment: Mail User Agent: the program or web app where you read and reply to mails.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin. Maybe it does what you need, maybe you can dive in the code to adapt it to your needs.
http://commonsinabox.org/documentation/plugins/buddypress-reply-by-email
https://github.com/r-a-y/bp-reply-by-email